# DataGridView shows type and not the value

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

I have a WinForms form with a DataGridView on.
The DataGridView are populated from a LINQ to SQL query as below.  When I run the code the gridview seems to show the column value and not the actual value.

The DataGridView does not have a design time source, and the columns have a DataPropertyName that is equal to the column in the database.

What am I missing that it doesn't display the actual value?

```
var q = (from r in db.MessagesReceived
         orderby r.ID descending
         select new { DateSent, DateReceived, ReceivedFrom}).Take(TopNumber);


//dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
dgv.DataSource = q;
dgv.Refresh();
```

[image]

Comment: What are `DateSent`, `DateReceived` and `ReceivedFrom`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is in the select

```
 select new { DateSent, DateReceived, ReceivedFrom})
```

should be

```
select new { DateSent=r.DateSent, DateReceived=r.DateReceived, ReceivedFrom=r.ReceivedFrom})
```

you are selecting the columns and not the values